# Sleep function error

Tags: c++, winapi

I have no idea what the problem is, nor do i know the error message, but i have an error on the sleep function, line 41. I cannot figure it out. thanks in advance guys------------(I have nothing else to say  but it wont post wihtout more words) EDIT--another error appears on the  if(GetAsyncKeyState) line

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>


using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

                bool exit=false;
                int hour, minute, second=0;
    cout<<"Enter the hour: "<<endl;
    cin>>hour;
    system("cls");
    cout<<"Enter the minute: "<<endl;
    cin>>minute;
    system("cls");
    while(exit==false) {
if(minute>9 && second>9)
{
    cout<<hour<<":"<<minute<<":"<<second;

}
if(minute<10 && second<10)
{
    cout<<hour<<":0"<<minute<<":0"<<second;

}
if(minute<10 && second>9)
{
    cout<<hour<<":0"<<minute<<":"<<second;

}
if(minute>9 && second<10)
{
    cout<<hour<<":"<<minute<<":0"<<second;

}

Sleep(1000);
second++;



if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_ESCAPE))
{
    exit=true;

}
            }



    cout<<endl;
return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

Comment: The code is C++. Please don't tag it C. Please tell us which is line 41. Please tell us the error message. Please don't post wall of code. Post cut down SSCCE.

Comment: The problem is, there's an error in your code.

Not very helpful? Neither was not including the actual error you are receiving.

Comment: I know what you did wrong, but don't feel inclined to answer because you won't bother to tell us the error message.

Comment: its like if you took the time to read my post you would realize that i explicitly stated tht i do NOT know the error message, as i do not think my IDE tells me

Comment: Your compiler does report an error message. And yes I read your question. And it's obvious to me what the error message is, and how to fix it. But you need to learn how to find error messages, read them and understand them.

Comment: How can you possibly know you're getting an error without being to tell what the error message actually says?  What IDE are you using?

Comment: what kind of a person goes out of their way to post a commen like htat? you guys hsould be ashmaed of yourselves. if you dont want to help, dont help. my post does not affect you

Comment: codeblocks. im sure it has one but i cannot find it.

Comment: @joe _'i do NOT know the error message'_ How can that be, if you're asking for it?!? Don't got how your IDE represents errors??

Comment: nope,i have yet to find it. it gives me a red dot and wont compile, but i cannot yet see the error message

Comment: _'commen like htat?'_ What in particular? Couldn't detect any offensive comment ....

Comment: XY problem, [PEBKAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_error#PEBKAC) not worth any more efforts answering! Would downvote again if I could ...

Answer (score 1):

I give in. Here's the answer. You did not include the windows header file.

```
#include <windows.h>
```

That's why the compiler complained. It could not find declarations of the API calls you made. The documentation for the API calls you make lists this requirement.

But you are really going to need to find where your compiler reports errors. If you can't see the error messages then you are in deep trouble.

Comment: im not even sure what that is. thank you

Comment: @joe It's under: View->"Error List" to bring the window back in case you closed it.

Comment: Bad didactics! You gave up to quickly on a nagging, dumb and advice resistant user ...

Comment: @g You are probably right!!

Comment: @joe So, now what? You've gone quiet.

Answer (score 0):

**Work on asking better questions!**

I can tell you're new to C++, but one of the things you need to work on is *being consistent*. Consistency involves the following steps :

- Does my code follow the same style, am I following the same pattern of logic?
- Do I use the same type of functions instead of spreading out over many APIs?
- Do I always comment the same way on my code?

Those may not seem important as a beginner, but they greatly improve readability and help others see your problem more easily. Another thing you should work on is [proper indentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style).

As far as your code goes, I believe you intended to include many of the statements that you wrote in your loop, which you didn't. You also use a mixture of Windows functions and system functions, which is horrid in my opinion ( not mentioning unsafe ). You should use one or the other. Your way of getting the time is pointless, since there is a standard function you could easily find with a proper search engine. Your Sleep() function is fine, but you may not understand that the system pauses execution of the thread during the duration you pass as a parameter. To avoid this, you should make use of some sort of timer or find a better way of printing output. You didn't include the correct header files, which is important in C++. You might also want to try a for-loop instead of a while-loop for this situation.

Overall, your code is very grotesque and poorly written. I can tell you are young, new, foreign, or stupid. You really should look up more of the documentation for these things before asking a poor question. I will give you a reprieve with my vague answers, but I believe that it will at least help you find some answers on your own.